# Can't guess default raspberry password

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-os

I've been trying to establish ssh connection with my raspberry by adding config files (wpa_supplicant.conf, ssh) to boot section of sd card with raspberry OS. I've done everything right and usually after these steps I could easily connect to my raspberry.
But, now I can't do this.
Whenever I try to log into raspberry using 'pi' as login and 'raspberry' as password, it says that this is incorrect password. I tried reinstalling OS on sd card; however, it didn't help.
I don't have any other opportunities other than connecting to raspberry wirelessly.

I have Raspberry Pi 4B and Raspberry OS 64-bit

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you are using the latest release of raspbian. Developers have made a huge step forward to the security and there is no more default user *pi* and password *raspberry*, no need of the wpa_supplicant.conf & ssh files (but they are still work).

For headless setup you can press settings button in the last version of Raspberry Pi Imager and configure User, Wi-Fi, SSH and so on.

Scroll down to the **Headless setup** chapter
https://www.raspberrypi.com/news/raspberry-pi-bullseye-update-april-2022/

Comment: Indeed. /boot/wpa_supplicant.conf still works expected and it seems the presence of /boot/ssh enables ssh but this was my first time using Raspberry Pi Imager and I didn't read any docs.  I was very confused as to why pi@ and "raspberry" were rejected.

Answer (score 2):

I created a guide with images to do this [here](https://shiningmantra.com/the-new-headless-raspberry-pi-setup-2022-rpi-org-disowned-username-pi/):

As per the official raspberry blog at https://www.raspberrypi.com/news/raspberry-pi-bullseye-update-april-2022 the default username password will no longer be allowed for headless login.

Basically there are two methods

1. Use the updated raspberry pi imager too from [here](https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/imager/imager_1.7.2.exe)
2. manually add `userconf` file in the boot directory with `username:encrypted-password` as a single line. to generate encrypted-password string use `echo 'mypassword' | openssl passwd -6 -stdin` tested on win 10

Answer (score 1):

For me it was a **wrong username**. So of cause the password was also wrong.

Try to open the Terminal on the Raspberry Pi and look at the green text before the @. This is you username. For example:
`username@raspberrypi: ⁓ $`

If you want to connect to the Raspberry Pi via SSH try `ssh username@raspberrypi.local`. Then the password which you remember should also be correct.